# Java Spring Boot Static Files

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im starting java spring today and i have a problem with it. I want to open my .html page when url trigger my controller. I have done it Python Django and c# ASP.NET before but now i dont understand why it doesnt work.

Spring Boot Version : 1.5.3.RELEASE

## HomeController

```
package berkin.kodgemisi.springbootstarter.home;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@Controller

public class HomepageController {

    @RequestMapping(path="/")
    public String index(){
        return "html/index.html";
    }
}
```

Its so simple. If url is "/" redirect to index.html but im confused. Its my HTML page.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Hello World </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This page cant be simple anymore

Is there something wrong with my dependencies? Should i write it?

Also i found a solution on stackoverflow. One person said

> mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"

#

> I guess there should be something like "web.xml" but i dont have it

Am i have to write something like this above?
[image: File Order]

## ERROR

[image: Error]

## CONSOLE

https://pastebin.com/EJpSVdQV

## POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>berkin.kodgemisi.hr</groupId>
    <artifactId>kodgemisi.hr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HR App</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.190</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `return "redirect:/index"` that means exactly what it says: redirect to the `/index`, which means that you need also to have a method supporting `/index` endpoint (and you don't show you have one).

If you just want to return a page from template, you need to have just `return "index";`.

If your resource handlers are set up correctly, that will look for appropriate file and return it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i changed it but my problem still exist. Please look up first comment. I will edit a few seconds later

Comment: There is not enough information. You don't show how your handlers configured, and you don't show what the actual error is. At least post some logs related to the method `index()` invocation.

Comment: I changed my first post. Should i write web.xml file or smt. else? What should i configure?

Comment: Well I already told you - show logs of the error. "Doesn't work" tells nothing.

Comment: Sure i will write it to the first post. Hang on

Comment: This is not logs, it's an error page. You need to add logs. I suggest you just google some step by step tutorial and follow it to build the hello world spring boot application. Blind tries is bad choice here.

Comment: Is this enough @Battle_Slug

Comment: @Berkin No, that's not enough, because your logs show only the initialization process and show nothing about the error that happens when you try to hit the url. If your logs don't show any error when you hit the url of concern, you need to elevate the debug level. If it's INFO, make it DEBUG. As soon as you see there how the application reacts on the invocation of target url, show that part of the logs.

Comment: But again, I suspect you aren't completely following some parts of the tutorial/documentation and thus experience difficulties. Spring Boot docs are very extensive.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t use @EnableWebMvc in spring boot, it will be autoconfigured if spring-web is included as maven dependency.

Which templating engine are you using? If you don't use a templating engine, you can use for example thymeleaf. Just add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```